# "addItem" in Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to upload a .pdf file in the content of my Portal for ArcGIS with a python script. I'm trying with the "additem" REST operation. My code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import argparse
import os
import json

sourcePortal='https://xxx/arcgis'

def generateToken(username, password, portalUrl):
    '''Retrieves a token to be used with API requests.'''
    parameters = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username,
                                   'password' : password,
                                   'client' : 'referer',
                                   'referer': portalUrl,
                                   'expiration': 60,
                                   'f' : 'json'})
    response = urllib2.urlopen(portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/generateToken?',
                              parameters).read()
    try:
        jsonResponse = json.loads(response)
        if 'token' in jsonResponse:
            print("Token generated OK")
            return jsonResponse['token']
        elif 'error' in jsonResponse:
            print jsonResponse['error']['message']
            for detail in jsonResponse['error']['details']:
                print detail
    except ValueError, e:
        print 'An unspecified error occurred.'
        print e

def uploadFile(token):

    '''Creates a new item in a user's content.'''    
    parameters = urllib.urlencode({'title' : 'myreport',                                    
                                   'overwrite': 'true',
                                   'type' : 'PDF',
                                   'token' : token,
                                   'async' : 'true',
                                   'multipart' : 'true',
                                   'filename' : 'newfile',
                                   'f' : 'json'
                                   })
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://xxx/arcgis/sharing/content/users/admin/additem',
        parameters).read()
    return response


sourceToken = generateToken(username='xxx', password='xxx',
                            portalUrl=sourcePortal)

reply=uploadFile(sourceToken)
itemID = json.loads(reply)["id"]

pdfFile = open('C:\\xxx\\xxx.pdf')

parameters = urllib.urlencode({
    'file' : pdfFile,    
    'partNum': '1',
    'token' : sourceToken,
    'f' : 'json'})
print(urllib2.urlopen('https://xxx/arcgis/sharing/content/users/admin/items/'+ itemID + "/addpart",parameters).read())

parameters = urllib.urlencode({
    'token' : sourceToken,
    'f' : 'json'})
print(urllib2.urlopen('https://xxx/arcgis/sharing/content/users/admin/items/'+ itemID + "/commit",parameters).read())
```

I have a problem with the "addpart". Here is the message :

```
{"code":400,"message":"Unable to add part.","details":["Invalid or missing 'file' parameter."]}
```

Does anyone have an idea to figure this out?

Comment: Is this operation doing a POST or GET?

Comment: It does a POST :-)

Answer (score 1):

Per this (somewhat weak) [REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/add-item.htm) documentation, any file upload must be multipart (which you are correctly attempting) however the docs also say that "No item properties can be passed into the multipart call" so I would try removing the title, type, and filename from the initial multipart=true parameters. (which I believe are the 'Invalid' file parameters reported in the error response.)  Then after the multipart upload, post a call to UpdateItem to add the title, type and filename params to the ItemId.

**Basically, a file upload of user-content to Portal is at least 3 Posts:**

1. mostly-empty initial call to gain ItemId (hook)
2. content upload call to actually upload the file into ItemId
3. then Update to populate the properties

If the file is larger than 5Mb, then step 2 iterates in 5Mb chunks (think zip file parts.)